# How to create a jar file of a java project which internall uses some external jars

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I want to create a jar file of my project which is internally using some other external jars.
Basically what I am expecting is a single jar file which has all the class files and external files in it.
can someone help me in this

Comment: There is a option in eclipse to export all the dependent jar file contents in your jar file.

Comment: Hi Ankur, Thanks for reply can you help me in finding that option I am unable to find it

Comment: create a folder named "lib" in your project which you need to take a jar from. Add all your dependent jars to the "lib" folder in your project. Set the build path/ class path to the lib folder jars and build a jar from your project. Eclipse will be helpful in setting up build/class paths for a project.

Comment: @user2940486 : I have posted the answer, take a look at it.

Comment: are you creating runnable JAR file or simple jar file ?

Answer (score 0):

If your classes use external jar files then you need to enclose those jars into your jar file.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the project in eclipse then :

Click on 'export'->'Runnable Jar`

Here: Make sure you select **'Extract required libraries into generated JAR'**

This will extract all the libraries present on the classpath of your project. into the exported jar file